# Why did Deckard continue to track alone?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner

Given Deckard was initially recruited by the police department because they wanted to "keep things quiet", why would he continue to track the remaining replicants alone?

Specifically,

> After Roy kills Dr. Tyrell, a seemingly very rich and influential person, it would appear that things are past the point of being able to be kept quiet. However, in the end it is just Deckard that goes after the last two replicants. He even sends a police officer away when he arrives at J.F.'s; why wouldn't he bring backup to J.F.'s house?

If it is relevant I was watching "Blade Runner: The Final Cut".

Comment: Blade Runner's operate alone (suggested in both film and novel). This would also fit the trope of a 'hard-boiled' detective. Film-Noir is an obvious and documented influence on BR ('Future Noir'). In the novel Deckard mentions wanting to not share the bounty.

The other possible interpretation rests upon seeing Deckard as one of the newest generations of Replicant. If you accept this, then you'd send a Replicant in to hunt others to preserve human life and send one Replicant to save costs in case he failed.